# Authorization Failed to install new certificate on Windows server 2012

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to create a new certificate for my website which is hosted on Windows server 2012.

Currently, I have a self signed expired certificate. I would like to try Let's Encrypt SSL cert. So, I've downloaded latest version of Lets Encrypt from https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme/releases and ran wacs.exe from unzipped folder.

When I select N=Create new certificate and entered my domain, I'm getting below error.

[image]

Expected: Certificate installed 
Actual: Authorization failed error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the server is not reachable from the Internet. Your server must be accessible from Internet in order to allow Let's Encrypt systems to verify the ownership of the domain.

According to the error which appears (NXDOMAIN), it may be that the website is too new (DNS registers can take up to 48 hours to replicate), the DNS are not properly configured to point to your server, or maybe you have a firewall or filter which disallows external connections.

Make sure that you can reach your domain from Internet first and it points to your server, then try again to request a certificate.